# How to create this shape in Adobe Xd?

Tags: vector, adobe-xd

I need a shape with curved lines. How to create the below shape with curved lines in xd.

[image]

The result I need is like this.

[image]

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just use the pen tool to draw these types of shapes. You can also adjust the corner to determine whether it should be rounded of not.

Comment: The Pen tool can be used for this.  Are you unable to create curves with the Pen Tool?  There's [a tutorial here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4eFLosQVNo)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make it using the pen tool. Why take the long way when you can use shortcuts?

Still, if you want to achieve the result using the curved lines
Heres what you should do.

1. Double Click On the curved line
2. Then double-click again on the anchor points.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Anytime my friend :) and Welcome to GDSE. @AdeekshaSathsara

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the Pen tool for this, and use the click and drag functionality to make the curves as you draw them. Also you don't need so many anchor points. Three should suffice.

Not only is it more efficient to use the tool in this way, but it will also help you create better quality curves. Also, should you need to, it will also make adjusting the curves easier in the long run. Of course, using the Pen Tool takes some practice, but the more you practice the better you will get.

Anyway . . .

1. Click and drag the first anchor to extend a curve handle, about 45° down towards the left.
2. Click and drag downwards to create the second anchor with curve handles extending vertically.
3. Click and drag the last anchor to extend a curve handle, about 45° down towards the right

An example

[image]

For more fun and practice with Bézier curves, try [the Bézier game](https://bezier.method.ac/). *Note: I am not affiliated with this website in any way.*

Comment: Wow! I'll try this. Thank you very much for your time & answer.

Comment: When doing this, consider turning on the grid lines so your points will be more precise and not random.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll try that too.